# Total JS heap size increases about 120MB when placing a mongodb query

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I don't understand why heap size keeps increasing when i place a mongodb database query inside a function in my controller.

here is my router

```
import { Router } from "express";
import profileController from '../controllers/profileController';

class userRouter {
  public router: Router;

  constructor() {
    this.getRoutes();
  }

  getRoutes() {
    this.router.get("/profile-list", profileController.getProfileList);
  }
}

export default new userRouter().router;
```

here is my controller

```
import Profile from "../models/profile";

export class profileController {
  static async getProfileList(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
    try {
      const getList = await Profile.find();
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 200,
        message: "Success",
        data: getList,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

here is my model

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import { model } from "mongoose";

const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String,  default: ""},
},
{ timestamps: true }
);

export default model("profile", profileSchema);
```

Total heap size without getProfileList function => 135 MB

Total heap size after placing getProfileList function => 255 MB (specifically after putting const getList = await Profile.find(); )

Here I inspected the memory and found this in comparison:

TypeObject increased from 3MB to 99MB
(array) increased from 26MB to 88MB

Any please please help me understand why does it happen? or is it usual in such case.

[image: Screenshot of the comparison before and after]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using any limits, so using `await Profile.find();` will return all the documents in the database, so when you are making a call to your controller that will return all data from the database that can incresase the heap size a lot.

You can use `limit` and `skip` to implement pagination for your endpoint.

Also you should consider the fact that `Mongoose` library has to be loaded into your memory, connections to database and so on, that also requries RAM.

Comment: I just put a limit to 10 on old and new function, still the same memory use, also I added few more functions, like getProductList and getUserList, and it keeps increasing the memory by about 40MB for each new function. If I keep adding new function it will keep adding such huge memory again and again.

Comment: Yep, that probably that is due to the fact that you are using more and more Mongoose models in your code.

Comment: To proof that concept try adding two functions that are using the same model. You should see it bump the memory consumptions so big, only once

Comment: you are absolutely correct. So what to do if I have about 35 or more models. Is there any solution for this or it is what it is.

Comment: Well, I believe there is nothing you can do. That is just the way it works.

If you think that this is too much memory consumption for you, you can discard `Mongoose` and use raw `mongodb` driver.